'zsh: killed' - running C in vscode on mac
I am trying to learn C and am using VSCode on mac. I have installed the C/C++ extension and the Code Runner extension. I have also enabled the 'run in terminal' setting for Code Runner.
I also have clang and gcc installed.
Whenever I write a C program for the first time and click 'Run Code', it works fine and I get the output in the terminal. However, whenever I try to run it a second time, it just says 'zsh: killed'
I have also tried compiling the file and then running it with './helloWorld'. Again, it works fine the first time. But then it says 'zsh: killed     ./helloWorld'
What should I do?
Here is my clang version:
jonathanyang@Jons-Mac cProgramming % clang -v
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.31.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Here is my gcc version:
jonathanyang@Jons-Mac cProgramming % gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.31.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Here is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char myName[] = "Jon";
    printf("%s", myName);
    return 0;
}

Is there something I am missing? What is the zsh killed error?

"Killed" is just reporting that the program was subject to a SIGKILL. Usually that's due to a bug in your code, so we can't diagnose it without knowing anything about that code. Attaching a debugger should tell you (much) more about what's going wrong.

(are you writing files, interacting with shared memory resources, or doing similarly stateful operations that might explain one run being distinct from the next one?)

Anyhow -- zsh is only there in the error message because it's the parent process of the program you ran, so it's what gets the job of reporting the error back to you-as-the-user; if you started it from bash, it would be bash instead of zsh giving you the message, but that's just a question of which process is responsible for telling you that the problem took place, it has nothing to do with the actual problem itself.

I've added my code, it's just the main function.

I can imagine its a "bug" in vscode. It tries to reuse the terminal windows from the previous run but zsh is already done aka killed.

@TheFool, this particular error message is printed by zsh. It can't be exited -- couldn't print it.

tries to remember if the assignment syntax used puts a NUL terminator on the end of the string; been too many years since his last serious C work

@CharlesDuffy What does that mean?

@CharlesDuffy given nested shells are a thing, it can print it. But thats missing my point. Usually, vscode runs special purpose windows for these types of things. Could be that zsh appears here as its set to be some default shell. I guess what would be interesting is to see the task runner config. I recall for c you needed some special config file.

@JonathanYang, re: "What does that mean?" -- your myName array should be four characters -- 'J', 'o', 'n' and a NUL. If it doesn't have the NUL on the end then it's invalid, and software that tries to interact with the string can run off the end of it and into other memory. I don't remember if the syntax you used stores the NUL automatically or not.

@Charles Duffy, Re "Usually that's due to a bug in your code", That's SIGSEGV ("Segmentation fault"). SIGKILL ("Killed") is usually sent manually, or by the system when resource limits are exceeded.

My assumption can be tested by closing out the run/output window between runs. I feel the error will not show.

@The Fool, Re "given nested shells are a thing, it can print it.", No. The only thing the parent shell could print is zsh: killed zsh. It has no way of knowing a grandchild was killed.

@JonathanYang, ...can you reproduce the problem without using VS Code, just invoking your program directly in a terminal you started yourself? (If so, that lets us discard all VS-Code-specific theories).

Echoing what @CharlesDuffy implied: there's likely something wrong with VS Code.  Something is leaving either the environment or the executable file itself in an invalid state after it's run once.  For example, trying to link a 32-bit shared object to a 64-bit executable would result in the killed message.  Simply compile the executable, find it in your directory tree from a command-line shell that was not started by VS Code, and try running it from the command line with something like /path/to/executable/helloWorld or cd to /path/to/executable then run ./helloWorld.
